# What is the difference between "class A : B<C>" and "class A<T> : B<T> where T : C"?

Tags: c#, generics

I am trying to create a derived class from a generic class, and I was wondering what the differences are between

```
public class A<T> : B<T> where T : C
{
}
```

and

```
public class A: B<C>
{
}
```

Inside class A there probably will be no code, since (for now) it will not behave different from class B. I only want to distinguish the two classes.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Say you had a class

```
public class D : C
{
}
```

Then in your first example the below is valid.

```
var a = new A<D>
```

You can use any class for `T` that is ultimately derived from C.

Whereas your second code is hard coded to have B use C for the genric type parameter and is not generic.

Answer (score 2):

It is a [Constraints with generics in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx), for sample:

In

```
public class A<T> : B<T> where T : C
{
}
```

The generic `T` must be a `C` type or a child of it (what is a abstraction).

In

```
public class A: B<C>
{
}
```

The generic is `C`.

Answer (score 2):

In your first example, `A` is a generic class, of type `C`. It also inherits from class `B` of type `C`.

Your second example has the following properties:

`A` is *not* a generic class. It inherits from class `B` of type `C`.

So, they are actually quite different.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you are making the the `A Class` **as a generic class** that that `T` must be given when instantiating the class.

```
A<C> instance = new A<C>();
```

In the second example, The `A Class` **is not a generic class**, since when instantiating the `A Class` there is no need to declare the `T` since its done automatically behind the scenes based on the `A Class` declaration.

```
A instance = new A();
```

**Another difference**

If you have the given hierarchical inheritance tree:

[image]

At the first example, when you instantiate the `A` class, every one of the inherited class can be used as the `T`.

At the second example, you can Instantiate the `A` class and specify the `C2` class, so only classes that inherit from `C2` can be used insde the `A` class.

Answer (score 0):

In second option you will end up with a non-generic class `A`, whereas in the First option you will have generic class `A`